# Error while executing "sed" command that uses shell variables

Tags: bash, sed, variable-substitution

This has been driving me crazy...

I want to list files in a dir and, based on the number interate on all files except the latest one, here is the code snipplet

---

```
FILECOUNT=$(ls -lt [dir]*.log | grep -c .log )
for (( c=2; c<=$FILECOUNT; c++ ))
do
FILEDIR=$("ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n '$c p'")
```

---

I have been having issues with `$c` interpretation, the format above works but the sed command fails... although entering the last line of the log in the cli works like a charm

---

```
 FILECOUNT=24

 (( c=2 ))

 (( c<=24 ))

C is : 2

 'ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n '\''2 p'\'''

 line 41: ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n '2 p': No such file or directory
```

---

any help would be greatly appreciated!

the `[dir]` is obviously a valid directory

Comment: Please consider switching to a shell such as `zsh` where you can order and select files by modification time using *glob qualifiers* ex. `for f in dir*.log(Om[1,-2]); do` or `for f in dir*.log(om[2,-1]); do`. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue you have is that you put everything in the command substitution in double-quotes:

```
FILEDIR=$("ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n '$c p'")
```

This would instruct the shell to locate an executable file with *verbatim name* `ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n '$c p'"` and no arguments, as opposed to executing the command `ls` with options `-1t` and operand `[dir]*.log` whose output is to be piped to the executable `sed` with option `-n` and argument `'$c p'`. Try to remove the double-quotes, as in

```
FILEDIR=$(ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n '$c p')
```

**However** then you will face the issue that the variable expansion is disabled in your single-quoted `sed` command. One [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584926/12231187) is to break the single-quote argument and place the variable in a double-quoted interjection, as in

```
FILEDIR=$(ls -1t [dir]*.log | sed -n "$c"' p')
```

Also, I must issue the mandatory warning [not to parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). ;)

Comment: @Jay You're welcome :) But as mentioned, you may want to look at methods that don't involve the output of `ls` for future applications - filenames can "legally" contain a lot of crazy characters, some of which (in particular spaces and newlines) will confuse your shell and lead to strange behavior.